# Phaser Creature Example: Phaser.Creature is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm really having trouble with getting the [dragon example](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/animation/creature-dragon) for animations made with Creature to work.

I always get this error:

> phaser28.js:47283 - Uncaught TypeError: Phaser.Creature is not a
>   constructor

The lines in question are these:

```
 creature: function (x, y, key, mesh, group) {

    if (group === undefined) { group = this.world; }

    var obj = new Phaser.Creature(this.game, x, y, key, mesh);

    group.add(obj);

    return obj;

},
```

I'm using the full phaser 2.8.0. build which is supposed to include all modules. I tried to aditionally load all kinds of other js files from the creature runtimes but just can't get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered a problem similar to this: http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/28612-ccreature-is-not-a-constructor/

Try adding these modules to your project (v2.8.0):

- **[Creature](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser-ce/blob/master/build/custom/creature.js)**
- **[Phaser Creature](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser-ce/blob/master/build/custom/phaser-creature.js)**

Import them into your index:

```
<head>
<title>Phaser Test</title>
<script src="phaser.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!--Framework-->
<script src="creature.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="phaser-creature.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="game.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!--Code game-->
</head>
```